# How can I import csv-file with multi-character delimiters into dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, separator

I have this movies.csv [csv-file](http://movies.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/9f66a575a6cfaaf7e43177317461d057) which I am to import into dataframe named 'movies'. But I have some troubles with erasing these #, ##, ###, #### delimiters. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlv3P.png)
I tried this code:

```
    import pandas as pd
my_cols=["Title", "US Gross", "Worldwide Gross", "Production Budget", "Release Date", "Distributor", "Source", "Major Genre", "Creative Type","Director","Rotten Tomatoes","Rating","IMDB Rating","IMDB Votes"]
movies=pd.read_csv('movies.csv', 
                   sep="\#\#\#\#",
                   quotechar='"',
                   names=my_cols,
                   engine="python")
movies
```

but it still leaves this sign "#" and makes only 1 column. Please, help to fix this.

here is a few lines from CSV:
Title#US Gross#Worldwide Gross#Production Budget#Release Date#Distributor#Source#Major Genre#Creative Type#Director#Rotten Tomatoes Rating#IMDB 
The Land Girls#146083#"146083"#"8000000"#12.6.1998#Gramercy####""##6,1#1071

Comment: Can you share a couple of lines from the CSV in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a regex in the `sep` parameter to indicate that you want only on `#` character as the separation, like this:

```
my_cols=["Title", "US Gross", "Worldwide Gross", "Production Budget", "Release Date", "Distributor", "Source", "Major Genre", "Creative Type","Director","Rotten Tomatoes","Rating","IMDB Rating","IMDB Votes"]
movies=pd.read_csv('Downloads/movies.csv', 
                   sep="#{1}",
                   quotechar='"',
                   names=my_cols,
                   engine="python",
                   skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, also gives an error (screenshot) https://ibb.co/NFTbfD0

Comment: I think it has to do with how the columns are read from the file. If you go back to what you did earlier, i.e., adding the column names yourself, then it works (notice that the file is missing the last of your columns: "IMDB Votes"). I've modified the solution accordingly.

Comment: wow, you really fixed it, but could you help me to get rid of these quotation marks? https://ibb.co/XpsQ2sg

Comment: Just do this: `movies = movies.replace(to_replace='"', value="", regex=True)`

Comment: I thought everything was done, but understood that i should fix this thing "the first row of your input file (column names) contains a.o. Rotten Tomatoes Rating (one column), wherease your column list contains two columns: Rotten Tomatoes and Rating" and now after its combination, again it says "Expected 13 fields in line 803, saw 14. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used." Turned out "#" means number there ("Revolution#9"). What can I do with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what the issue is, but if it's that the csv file has the separator character # as part of the string value in some rows, then the problem is with the original file and there's not much you can do via read_csv. I suggest that you fix those in the original csv. Open it, identify the rows where there's a # used in a way other than as a separator (which is probably the rows that give you the error), and change it to something else. Hopefully there's not many cases like this, but I don't see another way around this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I noticed is that your CSV file has a **single** *#* as
a separator.

Admittedly, it contains sometimes a few hashes in a sequence, but it means only
that a number of input fields are **missing** (they are empty strings).
This is why hashes located by principle **between** consecutive fields
are actually in your file next to each other.

Another thing to notice is that the default behaviour of *read_csv* is that
such empty strings are converted to *NaN*, which is not the best choice for
missing e.g. strings.

To switch off this feature, pass *na_filter=False*.

Note also that *quotechar* is not needed, as you passed just its default value.

*engine* parameter is probably also not needed.

The next remark, concerning column names, is that the first row of your
input file (column names) contains a.o. *Rotten Tomatoes Rating* (**one**
column), wherease your column list contains **two** columns: *Rotten Tomatoes*
and *Rating*, which are not present in your input.

So drop *names* argument (you actually attempt to read **all** columns).

Another subtle detail: If you passed *names* parameter, it means that:

- Your input **does not contain** any row with column names.
- You specify them on your own.
- Data rows are read starting from the **first** input row.

Because your file **does** contain column names, they are actually read
as the **first row of data**.

If you want to "limit" the reading to a subset of source columns,
pass *usecols* parameter with a column list, but as I see, you don't
need it.

So, to sum up, try the following code:

```
movies = pd.read_csv('movies.csv', sep='#', na_filter=False)
```

## Edit following the comment as of *11:58:03Z*

If "additional" hashes are **only** in the first field (e.g. *Revolution#9*
in row 803), there is possible to cope with this problem.

The idea is to:

- Write a specialised parser, performing **reverse split** on each line
  read from the input file.
- Read column names (from the first input line) with just this parser (thus
  consuming the first line).
- Create a DataFrame calling *pd.DataFrame* with:

  - just this parser as *data* (it will read "further" lines, i.e. lines
    containig data),
  - column list read before as *columns*.

To do it, define the parser as follows:

```
def parse_file(fn, sep, maxsplit):
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.strip().rsplit(sep, maxsplit)
            yield [ tt.strip('"') for tt in fields ]
```

Then, instead of *read_csv*, run:

```
myParser = parse_file('input.csv', '#', 12)
cols = next(myParser)
df = pd.DataFrame(myParser, columns=cols)
```

Note that the task to remove double quotes surrounding some fields
has been implemented in the parser (see *tt.strip('"')*).

However the DataFrame read this way has all columns of *string* type.
So you should cast particular columns to their proper types.
E.g. all 3 "budget" columns can be cast to *int* and *Release Date* to *datetime*.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation! But I have just tried this code. Unfortunately, it says: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 803, saw 14

Comment: I tested my code on first about 10 lines of your input file. Take a look at the indicated line (803). Apparently it contains too many *#* characters, dividing the content into fields. Then decide how to fix this error.

Comment: there are several such lines, and it turned out that in this line 803: 
 Revolution#9#9118#"9118"#"350000"#15.11.2002###Thriller/Suspense##""##7,3#252     it is a name of the movie "Revolution #9" i.e. "Revolution №9", but my teacher told not to change csv-file, but fix this problem with a code

Comment: If you use *#* as a field delimiter, then it is **forbidden** to use the
same char in any other function. Your input file is definitely malformed
(e.g. in line 803, which contains just a *#* as the string **content**).
So this file should be first brought to an order, e.g. by changing the
delimiter to some other char, e.g. *|* (it is not used in your input file).
Only then it can be processed with *read_csv*.
Or you should ask another question, how to cope with such case,
precisely stating where is the actual problem and giving an example of
a malformed line.